# PHP Mailer is not sending 'field input'

Tags: php, email, mailer

Sorry folks, but I think I have a little problem (easy to solve) but I am not getting the solution by myself. Could you help me out?

The problem I am facing is this:
- the PHP script (handled by PHP mailer) is sending an e-mail, but not the information people fill in at the form.

Here is the php script I use:

```
<?php
$to = "user@domain.com"; 
$subject = "Request";
$message = "<h1>Request</h1>";
$message .= "<strong>street</strong>: $_POST['street']";
$message .= "<strong>store</strong>: $_POST['store']";
$headers  = "From: request@domain.com";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if( $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){ echo "SENT"; } else { echo "There    
was a problem"; }
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the $_POST['street'] values being passed succesfully through from the form? Would be better to pull those out first and append them to the string, which gives you a chance to validate the user input.

Comment: You're doubling your `mail()` which I have no idea why. Plus, you first need to assign your variables right off the bat, such as `$street=$_POST['street'];` then do the same for the other(s). Also your `From:` kind of doesn't make sense. If you have someone filling out a form, don't they have to enter their email address?

Comment: Get rid of `$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` then do `if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){ echo "SENT"; } else { echo "There was a problem"; }`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$to = "user@domain.com"; 
$subject = "Request";
$message = "<h1>Request</h1>";
$message .= "<strong>street</strong>:".$_POST['street'];
$message .= "<strong>store</strong>:".$_POST['store'];
$headers  = "From: request@domain.com";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if( $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){ echo "SENT"; } else { echo "There    
was a problem"; }
?>
```

Comment: Please leave a small note as to explain what you changed and why.

Comment: I have change these two line

$message .= "<strong>street</strong>: $_POST['street']";
$message .= "<strong>store</strong>: $_POST['store']";

with this code of line

$message .= "<strong>street</strong>:".$_POST['street'];
$message .= "<strong>store</strong>:".$_POST['store'];

i have concatenate POST variables. You directly pass the variables

Answer (score 2):

There were a few problems with your code.

Your headers `$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";` were malformed and were adding `1.0  etc.` to the `From:` therefore resulting in `1.0 <request@domain.commime-version>`

Also, your `mail()` function was being executed twice, therefore sending 2 emails at the same time.

I fixed your headers including your `mail()` by removing `$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` and modifying the `if` condition.

Assuming this is what you are using for an HTML form which I used to test it with:

```
<form method="POST" action="mail_handler.php">
<p>
  <label>Street:<br>
    <input name="street" type="text">
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label>Store:<br>
    <input name="store" type="text">
  </label>
</p>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

### mail_handler.php

```
<?php
$to = "user@domain.com";
$subject = "Request";
$message = "<h1>Request</h1>";
$message .= "<strong>street</strong>:".$_POST['street'];
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<strong>store</strong>:".$_POST['store'];

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "From: user@domain.com" . "\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: user@domain.com" . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
echo "SENT"; } else { echo "There was a problem"; }
?>
```

More information on headers and the `mail()` functions can be found by visiting the PHP.net Website at the following URL: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php